# links to products redirects to main products page

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help with a bug in links to a product detail page.
The issue I'm experiencing is when I click on any of the products, I get send back to the main products page. I've read all of the message board I could find, and nothing seems to fix the problem. Using what I've read, I narrowed it down to the .htaccess. Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^products/$ products/products.php
    RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/$ products/product.php?id=$1
    RewriteRule ^receipt.php$ receipt/ [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^contact.php$ contact/ [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^products.php$ products/ [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(products/products.php[0-9]+)$ /$1/
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
    RewriteRule ^product.php$ products/%1/?
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your URL structure or what the link looks like to a product page (which is vital if you want to know about what happens with the combination of URL and htaccess).

Easier would be to use an online htaccess checker like here http://htaccess.mwl.be/ . This allows you to insert your htaccess (or part of it) and the income URL (your product url) and see what the result is. You can decide if it's the problem based on that and try to fix/tweak it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did that and it told me non of the rules or conditions were met.Out of frustration I deleted the htaccess file, and that changed nothing, so the bug must be somewhere else, I've looked at multiple pages of my code, and cannot find a single thing that could be causing it.